# Custom Validation Attribute with Custom Model Binder in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-validators, custom-model-binder

I apologise for the amount of code I have included.  I've tried to keep it to a minimum.

I'm trying to have a Custom Validator Attribute on my model as well as a Custom Model binder.  The Attribute and the Binder work great seperately but if I have both, then the Validation Attribute no longer works.

Here is my code snipped for readability.  If I leave out the code in global.asax the custom validation fires but not if I have the custom binder enabled.

Validation Attribute;

```
public class IsPhoneNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //do some checking on 'value' here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Useage of the attribute in my model;

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a contact number")]
    [IsPhoneNumberAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Custom Model Binder;

```
public class CustomContactUsBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ContactFormViewModel contactFormViewModel = bindingContext.Model as ContactFormViewModel;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contactFormViewModel.Phone))
            if (contactFormViewModel.Phone.Length > 10)
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Phone", "Phone is too long.");
    }
}
```

Global asax;

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(ContactFormViewModel)] = 
  new CustomContactUsBinder();
```

Comment: Technically, you aren't really doing any model binding with your custom model binder.  This is just using a model binder for validation only (which isn't what model binders are for).  If you really need to have a separate validation for the phone number length, this could be an attribute as well.

Comment: @Derek, whilst I agree with you I am using this as an example to the guys here on what is possible.  I have propper binding code in there as well and what I presented here is a snippet only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are calling the `base` method:

```
protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    ContactFormViewModel contactFormViewModel = bindingContext.Model as ContactFormViewModel;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contactFormViewModel.Phone))
        if (contactFormViewModel.Phone.Length > 10)
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Phone", "Phone is too long.");

    base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
}
```

Comment: AAAahhhh!  Just checked SVN.  I removed it this morning for some silly reason and forgot about it!  Thanks @Darin.